# getTargetEl().down('input') of textarea returns null

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm working whith EXTJS, and i need to modify the style of xtype: 'textarea'. 
So what i'm using (which works perfectly for xtype: 'textfield') is this :

```
Ext.getCmp('idOfComponent').getTargetEl().down('input').setStyle('border-width', '0px');
```

The problem is that in the case of a textarea, this code : Ext.getCmp('id').getTargetEl().down('input') returns null.
Any leads ?

Comment: Have you tried `.down('textarea')` instead?

Comment: it works ! 
Thank you !
how can i marke your answer as a valid one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.down('textarea')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

down() method is a Container's method which should be invoked directly on the Container objects viz (Panels, Windows etc). You're trying to invoke down() method on a Ext.dom.Element class where you should be using select(), hence it does not work. Try changing it to the following.

```
Ext.getCmp('idOfComponent').el.select('input').first().applyStyles('border-width : 0px');
```

"el" property of the component gives you the reference to Ext.dom.Element that supports/backs the UI. In that element you can select() for more child elements and of those elements you can choose to select only the first() matching element.